# Basis enumeration of large lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to combine two list in the following way without using `Table` or any loop structure.

```
genList[n_] := Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 4], n]  (* list generating function*)
```

The two lists that needs to be combined are:-

```
list1 = genList[3]
list2 = genList[4]
```

What I want to achieve is as follows:-

```
Partition[
          Flatten[
                 Table[{list1[[i]], list2[[j]]}, {i, 1 
                 Length[list1]},{j,1 Length[list2]}]
                 ]
       ,8]
```

So I simply need to enumerate each of the elements of list 1 combined with all of the elements of list 2.

What would be an efficient way of doing this with large lists?

Let's say with `Length[list1] = 100` and `Length[list2] = 200`.

Also `Length[list2] > Length[list1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Join @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}] (* or *)
Flatten /@ Tuples[{list1, list2}] (* or *)
Join @@ Outer[Join, list1, list2, 1]
```

> {{5, 3, 5, 4, 9, 2, 10, 6}, {5, 3, 5, 4, 10, 6, 4, 7},
>    {5, 3, 5, 4, 2,
>      1, 7, 1}, {5, 3, 5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 9},
>    {2, 6, 9, 5, 9, 2, 10, 6}, {2, 
>     6, 9, 5, 10, 6, 4, 7},
>    {2, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 7, 1}, {2, 6, 9, 5, 6, 6, 
>     1, 9}, {10, 8, 9, 6, 9, 2, 10, 6},
>    {10, 8, 9, 6, 10, 6, 4, 7}, {10, 
>     8, 9, 6, 2, 1, 7, 1}, {10, 8, 9, 6, 6, 6, 1, 9}}

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of kglr's approach that employs `ArrayFlatten` instead of mapping `Flatten`. Notice also that I changed `genList` so that it produces [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496); this is crucial for performance.

```
genList[n_] := RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, 4}];
m = 100;
n = 100;
list1 = genList[m];
list2 = genList[n];

a = Partition[Flatten[Table[{list1[[i]], list2[[j]]}, {i, 1 Length[list1]}, {j, 1 Length[list2]}]], 8]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Flatten /@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = ArrayReshape[
     Tuples[{list1, list2}],
     {Length[list1] Length[list2], Dimensions[list1][[2]] + Dimensions[list2][[2]]}
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.026
>
> 0.0012
>
> 0.000095
>
> True